# How to get API data from node js to display on React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I'm learning react and node js and I'm making a macro calculator website and basically I get data (calories, macro ratio, etc..) from the user on client side then using those data I make a get request to edamam API server to get (foodID, uri, unit) and post those data again to get macros for each food. Then I calculated data. (It's working fine up to this point on the backend). And I want send this data to back to frontend to display and it's not working here. I'm using axios for the requests. I'm also not too sure it's right way to make API calls. Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you!

**Send data to backend from React**

```
async function postData(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    try{
      await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/getData", {formData})
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  }
```

**Node.js to make API calls and process data**

```
app.post("/getData", (req, res) =>{
  // data from React
  const targetKcal = req.body.formData.calories;
  const proteinRatio = req.body.formData.proteinRatio;
  const fatRatio = req.body.formData.fatRatio;
  const carbRatio = req.body.formData.carbRatio;
  const proteinSource = req.body.formData.proteinSource;
  const fatSource = req.body.formData.fatSource;
  const carbSource = req.body.formData.carbSource;
  const getURL = "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?";
  const postURL = "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/nutrients?";
  //GET Request to parse and get uri and foodID to post
  try{
    Promise.all([
      axios.get(getURL, {params :{"ingr" : proteinSource}}),
      axios.get(getURL, {params :{"ingr" : fatSource}}),
      axios.get(getURL, {params :{"ingr" : carbSource}}),
  
  ]).then(axios.spread((proteinData, fatData, carbData) => { 
    try{
     //post data to get macro info for each macros
    Promise.all([
      axios.post(postURL, {"ingredients" :[{"quantity":1, "measureURI": proteinData.data.hints[0].measures.filter(obj => obj["label"] === "Gram")[0].uri,"foodId":proteinData.data.parsed[0].food.foodId}]}),
 
      axios.post(postURL, {"ingredients" :[{"quantity":1, "measureURI": fatData.data.hints[0].measures.filter(obj => obj["label"] === "Gram")[0].uri,"foodId":fatData.data.parsed[0].food.foodId}]}),
  
      axios.post(postURL, {"ingredients" :[{"quantity":1, "measureURI": carbData.data.hints[0].measures.filter(obj => obj["label"] === "Gram")[0].uri,"foodId":carbData.data.parsed[0].food.foodId}]})
    
     ]).then(axios.spread((data1, data2, data3) => {

          let proteinKcal = data1.data.totalNutrients.ENERC_KCAL.quantity;
          let protein = data1.data.totalNutrients.PROCNT.quantity;
          let proteinFat = data1.data.totalNutrients.FAT.quantity;
          let proteinCarb = data1.data.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity;

          let fatKcal = data2.data.totalNutrients.ENERC_KCAL.quantity;
          let fatProtein = data2.data.totalNutrients.PROCNT.quantity;
          let fat = data2.data.totalNutrients.FAT.quantity;
          let fatCarb = data2.data.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity;


          let carbKcal = data3.data.totalNutrients.ENERC_KCAL.quantity;
          let carbProtein = data3.data.totalNutrients.PROCNT.quantity;
          let carbFat = data3.data.totalNutrients.FAT.quantity;
          let carb = data3.data.totalNutrients.CHOCDF.quantity;

          //Calculate each macros for target calories 
          const proteinTargetGram = (targetKcal * (proteinRatio / 100))/proteinKcal;
          const fatTargetGram = (targetKcal * (fatRatio / 100))/fatKcal;
          const carbTargetGram = (targetKcal * (carbRatio / 100))/carbKcal;
          
          proteinKcal *= proteinTargetGram;
          protein *= proteinTargetGram;
          proteinFat *= proteinTargetGram;
          proteinCarb *= proteinTargetGram;
          
          fatKcal *= fatTargetGram;
          fatProtein *= proteinTargetGram;
          fat *= fatTargetGram;
          fatCarb *= proteinTargetGram; 

          carbKcal *=carbTargetGram;  
          carbProtein *= proteinTargetGram;
          carbFat *= proteinTargetGram;
          carb *= carbTargetGram;

          const totalKcal = (proteinKcal + fatKcal + carbKcal).toFixed(0);
          const totalProtein = (protein + fatProtein + carbProtein).toFixed(0);
          const totalFat = (proteinFat + fat + carbFat).toFixed(0);
          const totalCarb = (proteinCarb + fatCarb + carb).toFixed(0);

          const data = {
            "totalKcal": totalKcal, 
            "totalProtein": totalProtein,
             "totalFat": totalFat,
             "totalCarb": totalCarb, 
             "proteinTargetGram": proteinTargetGram,
             "fatTargetGram": fatTargetGram,
             "carbTargetGram":carbTargetGram
            };
        
          //send back the data
          res.json(data);
          
    }))
    }catch(err) { console.log(err); }
  }));
  }
  catch (err) { console.error(err); }
});
```

**Use the data to display on React**

```
function Result() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getData = async ()=> {
      const response = await axios.get('/getData');
      setData(response.data);
    };
    getData();
  });
  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.map(item => item)}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Result
```

**Error message**

[image: chrome console error message]

-----------------------Edit-------------------------------------------

**Instead of res.json(data) I added below**

```
axios.post('/getData', data)
.then(res => console.log(res.json))
.catch(err => console.log(err.json));
```

**display on react**

```
function Result() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getData = async ()=> {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/getData');
      setData(response.data);
    };
    
    getData();
  });
  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**I still get an error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is generated because you are asking to a GET method that doesn't exist on backend, that's why you see 404 there.
You actually have a POST declared (getData), you should request to the POST method by passing the values on the body. something like this:

```
axios.post('/getData', {
// pass the formData here
  formData:{ 
      // calories: ...,
      // ...
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
    // update state
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Axios is fine, if you don't want to use an external package you can use fetch. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

For the render: you have to do something different, since you are receiving an object you should map on keys, change this:

```
<h1>{data.map(item => item)}</h1>
```

to something like this:

```
<h1>{Object.keys(data).map(key => key + ": " + data[key])}</h1>
```

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your quick reply :) I've done what you said and I still getting 404 error and I'm not sure why.. I've added what I wrote. I'm still getting all the data from API. It's just can't pass the data over to react. Thanks for you help again

Comment: I have probably explained myself wrong. The response is here `await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/getData", {formData})` assign it to a variable and handle it to set the state.

Comment: That's on node js right? And then axios.get('http://localhost:4000/getData') to retrive the data on react but I'm still getting 404.. it's frustrating :/

Comment: if you do axios.get it will check for a GET on backend, and you have only a POST method declared there, so it's expected a 404. 
function postData(e) is in frontend and here you need to retrieve and handle the response from your request.

Comment: Ohhh now I get it!! I had to send it back to the body and get the response from where I requested a post on frontend! What I was trying to do was send this data to other file where it shows the result  and it wasn't working that way. I really appreciate your help!! :)